# die roll program giving syntax error in python

Tags: python

```
    import random
#set counters
counter2=0
counter3=0
counter4=0
counter5=0
counter6=0
counter7=0
counter8=0
counter9=0
counter9=0
counter10=0
counter11=0
counter12=0
doubles=0

def main():
    #get input from user
    rolls = int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice?")
    for count in range(rolls+1)
        #roll dice
        die1 = random.randint(1,6)
        die2 = random.randint(1,6)
        #add up dice totals to counters
        if die1 + die2 = 2:
            counter2 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 3:
            counter3 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 4:
            counter4 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 5:
            counter5 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 6:
            counter6 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 7:
            counter7 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 8:
            counter8 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 9:
            counter9 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 10:
            counter10 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 11:
            counter11 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 12:
            counter12 += 1
        if die1 == die2:
            doubles += 1
    #print data
    print("2 - ", counter2, \
          "3 - ", counter3, \
          "4 - ", counter4, \
          "5 - ", counter5, \
          "6 - ", counter6, \
          "7 - ", counter7, \
          "8 - ", counter8, \
          "9 - ", counter9, \
          "10 - ", counter10, \
          "11 - ", counter11, \
          "12 - ", counter12, \
          "Doubles - ", doubles)
main()
```

the object of the program is to roll the 2 dice however many times the user wants, then list how many times the dice rolled 1,2, 3, 4, etc etc. the lines "die1 = random.randint(1,6) and die2 = random.randint(1,6) give me a syntax error and highlight the "die1" mind telling me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing a colon at the end of the `for` line.

Comment: putting a colon at the end of the for line gives a syntax error at the colon as well.

Comment: Why do not you use `for` for the counters variables?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed up your program a bit.

Notice the use of a generator expression in the nested join call for extra efficiency.

```
print '\n'.join(['' if not globals().update({'rolls' : [(__import__("random").randint(1,6),__import__("random").randint(1,6)) for count in range(int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice?")))]}) else '', '\n'.join("%d - %d" % (i, len(filter(lambda x: sum(x)==i, globals()["rolls"]))) for i in range(2,11)), "Doubles %d" % len(filter(lambda r:r[0]==r[1], globals()["rolls"]))]).lstrip()
```

Answer (score 1):

A few errors:

- `if` statement without colon
- equality test is `==`, not `=`
- a missing closing parenthesis
- global variables are inaccessible in function, make them local

So here's the corrected version:

```
import random

def main():
    #set counters
    counter2=0
    counter3=0
    counter4=0
    counter5=0
    counter6=0
    counter7=0
    counter8=0
    counter9=0
    counter10=0
    counter11=0
    counter12=0
    doubles=0

    #get input from user
    rolls = int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice?"))
    for count in range(rolls+1):
        #roll dice
        die1 = random.randint(1,6)
        die2 = random.randint(1,6)
        #add up dice totals to counters
        if die1 + die2 == 2:
            counter2 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 3:
            counter3 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 4:
            counter4 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 5:
            counter5 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 6:
            counter6 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 7:
            counter7 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 8:
            counter8 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 9:
            counter9 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 10:
            counter10 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 11:
            counter11 += 1
        if die1 + die2 == 12:
            counter12 += 1
        if die1 == die2:
            doubles += 1
    #print data
    print("2 - ", counter2, \
          "3 - ", counter3, \
          "4 - ", counter4, \
          "5 - ", counter5, \
          "6 - ", counter6, \
          "7 - ", counter7, \
          "8 - ", counter8, \
          "9 - ", counter9, \
          "10 - ", counter10, \
          "11 - ", counter11, \
          "12 - ", counter12, \
          "Doubles - ", doubles)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

in equality operator is `==` not `=`

```
if die1 + die2 == 2:



rolls = int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice?")) <- missing this parentheses
```

Comment: And yes i did fix this before i posted it, i just forgot to re-copy the code

Comment: you forgot to fix the first if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with the previous answers there is an issue with the `for` loop and missing `:`.
However your code can be greatly simplified if you are willing to embrace [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
This should help prevent further syntax errors as the code is much more condensed and relatively simple. The main difference is utilisation of the `defaultdict`.

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict    


def main():
    counter = defaultdict(int)
    rolls = int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice?"))
    for count in range(rolls):
        die1,die2 = random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6)
        counter[die1+die2]+=1
        if die1 == die2:
            counter['Doubles']+=1
    counter
    print('\n'.join('%s - %s '%(key,value) for key,value in counter.iteritems()))
```

Of course the output can be formatted any way you like to to suite your needs, ie ordered, sorted, etc

Basically in this case if the key does not exist in the dictionary one will be created and assigned the integer value of 0. Really the only change to your code was removing all the initialization and consolidating the if checks. The number can only ever be one numeric value and potentially 'Doubles'.